# bash shell script: Copy specific contents of a folder within a folder from every folder to a new folder on desktop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying my best to describe this situation. Thanks in advance.

STEP 1: copy image to folder on desktop to a new folder
 01, 02, 03,... rename image to thumb.jpg

STEP 2:
create a new .txt that contains the original folders name.

```
file=${01}
cd ~/Desktop/TEST
(while read $file; do

    find . -type f -name "*300x250.jpg" 2>/dev/null | \
      (while read s; do
      IFS='/' read -ra FOLDERS <<< "$s"
      THUM=${s%.*}
      mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$file/
      cp "$s" ~/Desktop/$file/Thumb.jpg
      file=${01+1}
    done
   )
)
```

Example:

**TEST_FOLDER CONTAINS**

```
AD-123456-44 -> AD-123456-44_300x250.jpg

MT-333333-11 -> MT-333333-11_300x250.jpg

SA-222222-33 -> SA-222222-33_300x250.jpg
```

**RESULTS TO THIS ON DESKTOP**

```
01 -> AD-123456-44.txt - thumb.jpg

02 -> MT-333333-11.txt - thumb.jpg

03 -> SA-222222-33.txt - thumb.jpg
```

Please see images below:

[image: Starting]

[image: Ending Result]

Comment: Is there a question here?  Sounds like you're just asking someone to write a script for you.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is extremely unclear. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please edit your question.  What do you want to achieve, what is the content of `$file`, what is your actual particular problem? What is the purpose of the script, its intentions, what it does and what you want it to do? To edit, click your post's [edit] link located a line below and to the left of the question, then paste in the requested material. Also, have a look at [ask].

Comment: On my bash, `file=${01}` does not do anything.  `echo $file` returns a blank.  And `file=${01+1}` does not work either.  Where did you get that syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your code, and decided to start over.  In my opinion, you made it more complex than it needs to be.  Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sourcedir=~/SO/sourcedir
targetdir=~/Desktop/TEST

targetsubdir_counter=1

cd $sourcedir

for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | egrep -v "^\.$")
do
    cd $dir

    if [ $targetsubdir_counter -lt 10 ]
    then
        targetsubdir_name="0$targetsubdir_counter"
    else
        targetsubdir_name="$targetsubdir_counter"
    fi
    newdir="$targetdir/$targetsubdir_name"
    mkdir -p $newdir

    for file in "*300x250.jpg"
    do
        cp $file $newdir/thumb.jpg

        textfilename=$(echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)_300x250.jpg$/\1.txt/')
        echo "$sourcedir/$dir" > $newdir/$textfilename
    done
    cd ..
    (( targetsubdir_counter = targetsubdir_counter + 1 ))
done
```

- the first `for` loops through every directory under `$sourcedir`.  The `find` ensures that only directories at the first level are processed.  The `egrep -v` removes the current directory (`.`).
- the target directory is created at the start of this loop.
- the name of the target directory is calculated from the counter.  Since you want to have `0x` if x<10, that is what the `if` does.
- the second `for` loops through the files that contain "_300x250.jpg" in their name.
- for each file found, it copies it to "thumb.jpg"
- and it echoes the source directory in the ".txt" file.  The name of that file is calculated in the previous line, using `sed`.

Note that I used `cp` and note `mv` since I wanted to keep the source directory intact.  I recommend you do the same, and only delete the source once you are satisfied with the results.